# android - Signed APK is crashing after using Proguard

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-proguard

I am using Proguard in my application for code obfuscation. Now when i am checking for Code Obfuscation, its showing positive result. But the signed APK that I am generating and running on a real android device, is getting crashed.

Infact, when I am running the application from Android Studio, it works fine.

Below is my `build.gradle(Module:app)` code:

```
android {

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ms.handyHR"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("\\handyHR.jks")
        storePassword "*****"
        keyAlias "sample"
        keyPassword "*****"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

}

And, this is my `proguard-rules.pro` file code:

```
-ignorewarnings
 -keepclassmembers class com.dom925.com.example.MyApp {
    public *;
 }

 -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,Signature
 -keep class com.parse.*{ *; }
 -dontwarn com.parse.**
 -dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
 -keep class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
 -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
     native <methods>;
 }
 -renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
 -keep public class * extends android.app.Application

 -keep class * implements java.io.Serializable {
     static final long serialVersionUID;
     private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
     private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
     private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
     java.lang.Object writeReplace();
     java.lang.Object readResolve();
     private *;
     void set*(***);
     *** get*();
 }
 -keepattributes Signature
 -keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
 -keep class com.example.MyApp.** { *; }
```

Also, need to tell you that, I also generated a normal apk file, and that worked. But, I am having issues running signed APK file in real android device.

Below are some other Proguard-Rules codes that I searched and applied but still facing the same problem. I tried the below codes:

Alternative 1:

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**

 #### -- OkHttp --

 -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.internal.**

 #### -- Apache Commons --

 -dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**

 -ignorewarnings
 -keep class * {
     public private *;
}
```

Alternative 2:

```
-dontwarn **CompatHoneyComb
-dontwarn **CompatHoneyCompMR2
-dontwarn **CompatCreateorHoneyCombMR2

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
```

Please advice me where I am getting wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My advice to you is that you actually sign your apk! It seems that you don't have `signingConfigs` in your `build.gradle` file. yeah, it can be the reason of crahing.

Comment: can that could be the reason that the application is crashing when installing the signed apk on a real device.

Comment: @MehranZamani  Sorry, this didn't work. Crashed again.

Comment: Update your question and also add error log too.

Comment: @MehranZamani  'build.gradle' is now updated, but still having same problem.

Comment: Android Monitor Logcat message